# pugixml vs tinyxml

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml, pugixml

Short question: any comments on comparison of pugixml and tinyxml please?

Details
I need to use an XML parser/writer. My software is written in C++.

It seems to me TinyXML and pugixml are both good options (RapidXML is good as well but its interface does not seem to be as easy as the above two as I have to manage data allocations myself).

Do people have any comments on the comparison between the two? I am working on an embedded platform so memory handling is important to me, and I need to be able to both parse and write XML data.

Speed is not that important but memory usage and easier interface are.

Thanks.
PS The XML files I am dealing with are fairly small (max size=1200bytes; max elements=6 or 7; XML files are fairly simple).

Comment: If it's any help I use TinyXML frequently, as do other professionals. I haven't used pugixml though!

Comment: Have used both and like pugixml more. Its simple, fast and has XPath support. But maybe this answer helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1448859/639650). If you stick with tinyxml, you might wan't to check out the c++ wrapper [link](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/).

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your replies.

@P3trus - Do you have any comments on 'memory usage' of pugixml and tinyxml - for both reading and writing? The files I am going to parse/write fairly small files and I am wondering which one would be more efficient.

Comment: have a look here [link](http://pugixml.org/benchmark/)

Comment: I used and tested both pugixml and TinyXML. I was impressed by pugixml's speed and low memory consumption. 
Also pugixml is much easier to use. 

The benchmarks tell the brutal truth http://pugixml.org/benchmark.html

TinyXML is more than 38 times slower and takes 28 times more memory for the same XML file than pugixml.
I could not believe it at first but my own test also confirmed it. 

I use pugixml in commercial applications to parse huge files. pugixml is a splendid parser..

Answer (score 3):

I used tinyxml, QtXml, boost property tree, and, as I remember, pugixml is fastest DOM xml-parser.

As for embedded, I used pugixml with about 9Mb xml-files - and all works fine and fast. But I don't know about your memory limitation - just write simple example and check.

Answer (score 1):

I have used TinyXML 6 months ago, I think it is excellent...

Answer (score 1):

You might look at Expat. I have used it for about 8 years in a commercial product without any trouble. It is open-source with a non-viral license.

Comment: I started off with Expat but expat does not have XML writing capabilities so I needed to move on to some other library that provides both parsing and XML creation capabilities.

Comment: There is "scew" for writing which uses expat.