# HTML, XHTML & XML parser in boost library

Tags: c++, boost

Is current release of boost 1.49.0 have any library, to parse html/xml documents. I know that pTree could be used for xml parsing but I am looking for sth more complete.
Thanks.

Comment: There is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042855/boost-and-xml-c) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Boost::Spirit it's that you looking for.

Comment: No, it’s not. Building your own XML parser, let alone a fault-tolerant HTML parser, is far from trivial (one word: encoding!).

Comment: I agree it isn't trivial, but that library make it possible (Spirit.Qi let you deal with encoding)

Comment: You *fundamentally* underestimate the required effort. Notably, Spirit.Qi won’t help you deal with the encoding issue, since you first need to *recognise* the used encoding.

Comment: I could not found any example on the web could you please give some example parsing html or xml with boost::spirit

Comment: Check boost example, there is full xml parser sample