# Dynamically generated Excel Xml (thru OpenXml) has a x: in all of its tags

Tags: excel, pivot, openxml

So, I dynamically created a PivotTable on an empty workbook (with data connections built already), and saved successfully: the document is even opened successfully why Excel GUI: everything seems right and working properly.

When I looked inside the package, I found the Xml tags have an extar x:, like workbook.xml is like bellow;.

```
<x:pivotCaches>
    <x:pivotCache cacheId=”1″ r:id=”rId4″ />
</x:pivotCaches>
```

Does anyone why we have this extra x:? It only happens after I add pivotCaches tag to the workbook.xml. I am using OpenXml 2.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` in `x:pivotCaches` is an *XML namespace prefix*.

For the XML to be [*namespace-well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), there must be a declaration that binds the namespace prefix, `x`, with a namespace URI, such as as `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main`.  Your XML fragment as it stands is not namespace-well-formed because it uses an undeclared XML namespace prefix.

The namespace prefix can be declared anywhere at or higher in the ancestry of its use:

```
<x:pivotCaches xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <x:pivotCache cacheId=”1″ r:id=”rId4″ />
</x:pivotCaches>
```

The namespace prefix can be omitted if a default XML namespace is instead declared:

```
<pivotCaches xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <pivotCache cacheId=”1″ r:id=”rId4″ />
</pivotCaches>
```

**See also**

- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)
- [Namespace usage in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40814406/290085)

Comment: Thanks. That's right. But how do I add xmlns ="..." for a Excel Workbook xml in OpenXml? I explored SetAttribute, AddNamespaceDeclaration, but neither seems apply for the default namespace!!!

Comment: You asked *Does anyone why we have this extra x:?*  I've answered that.  If you also have a coding question, you should post a new question that includes a [mcve] of what you've tried.  Your current question is not written to support your follow-up, and comments are not the place to build out the needed details.

Comment: Fair enough. You did answer the original question. And I also just got SetAttribute working but x: prefix is still there: suspect I need to remove xlmns:x explicitly. In any case, the presence of x: doesn't hurt and I'll just leave it there now that I understand its origin and implication. And this comment just intends to reach a conclusion for the original question. Thanks a lot a gain.

Answer (score 0):

The `x:` prefix is called an [XML Namespace](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp). You must also see an `xmlns:x` attribute in your XML file that indicates how to resolve the schema for this namespace.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, x: prefix is added, but by OpenXML implicitly. Guess I'd have to add the default namespace explicitly, to stop OpenXml from doing that.  Then, how do we add the default name for a Workbook thru OpenXml? I dig in and found AddNamespacedeclaration requires a prefix...